# SQL SUM(Case) Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
    SUM (CASE
                WHEN T6.Currency =
(
    SELECT A0.MainCurncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
)
                THEN T6.LineTotal
              else T6.TotalFrgn
            END) as [Mf.Amount],
```

I got this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery", but Sybase can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751241/sql-server-cannot-perform-an-aggregate-function-on-an-expression-containing-an)

Comment: We need to see the rest of the query.  What is `T6` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the overall query:

```
SELECT . . .
    SUM(CASE WHEN A0.MainCurncy IS NOT NULL
             THEN T6.LineTotal
             ELSE T6.TotalFrgn
         END) as [Mf.Amount],

FROM . . . LEFT JOIN
     @myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
     ON A0.MainCurncy = T6.Currency
```

Comment: Now ı get this error :Column 'CHERRYFIELDGMBHCOKG.dbo.ORDR.U_URETIMULKESI' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Include the column in the `GROUP BY`.